# How to compute $2^{\text{some huge power}}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I have to compute $$2^{p-1} \mod p$$ and show by Fermat's little theorem that $p$ isn't prime. I know what the question is asking but I'm not sure how to reduce the exponent on $2^{p-1}$ to a more reasonable number. Does that make sense? Any general tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Exponentiation by repeated squaring, reduce modulo $323$ at each step.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm still not quite sure but thanks for getting me in the right direction

Comment: Do you know the algorithm?

Comment: More explicitly, $2^2=4,4^2=2^4=16,16^2=2^8=256,\dots,(2^n)^2=2^{2n}$.  Applying a modulus like $323$ ensures that the numbers stay within reach of a handheld calculator or even pen-and-paper.

Comment: What I'm missing is why one would do anything fancy to test the primality of 323, which is obviously less than $20^2$ and turns out to be $17\cdot 19$ by quick trial and error.

Comment: @dfeuer: or even observation that it is $18^2-1$...

Comment: "I" get 157 as an answer, where by "I" I mean "Mathematica."

Comment: @dfeuer: I assume it's just as an exercise in Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: I get the same answer below.

Comment: @DanielFischer idea is the right one. Otherwise, $\large 2^{322}$ will cause an "overflow" in a 'current' computer.

Comment: $\large 2^{322}\ {\rm mod}\ 323 = \color{#0000ff}{\Large 157}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) is the way to go.

First write the exponent in base two: $322=101000010_{\text{two}}$

Compute $2^n\pmod{323}$:
$$
\begin{array}{}
2^n&n&\text{operation (mod $323$)}\\
\hline
1&0_{\text{two}}&\text{initialize}\\
2&1_{\text{two}}&\text{square and multiply by $2$}\\
4&10_{\text{two}}&\text{square}\\
32&101_{\text{two}}&\text{square and multiply by $2$}\\
55&1010_{\text{two}}&\text{square}\\
118&10100_{\text{two}}&\text{square}\\
35&101000_{\text{two}}&\text{square}\\
256&1010000_{\text{two}}&\text{square}\\
257&10100001_{\text{two}}&\text{square and multiply by $2$}\\
157&101000010_{\text{two}}&\text{square}\\
\end{array}
$$

---

**Explanation of the Method:**

When we square $a^n$, we double the exponent:
$$
\left(a^n\right)^2=a^{2n}
$$
When we square $a^n$ and multiply by $a$, we double the exponent and add one: $$
\left(a^n\right)^2\times a=a^{2n+1}
$$
Write the exponent in base two.

Squaring our number doubles the exponent (shifting it left by one bit). Multiplying the number by the base adds one to the exponent.

The goal is to get the desired exponent ($322=101000010_{\text{two}}$), building it up from the left, by shifting left and optionally adding one, when needed. Every time we shift the exponent, we square our number. Every time we add one to the exponent, we multiply our number by the base.

Comment: Yeah, I don't really know what you're doing there. I get the idea but I cannot follow that.

Comment: @user1874239: I've added some explanation. Let me know if there are still questions.

Comment: Much clearer! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

$\large\color{#888888}{\mbox{Following}}\ {\tt\mbox{@Daniel Fischer}}\ \color{#888888}{\mbox{comment}}$:

```
/* mod_0.cc
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553472/how-to-compute-2-textsome-huge-power/553810#553810
*/
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef unsigned long long ullong;
const ullong ONE=ullong(1),N323=ullong(323),N322=ullong(322);


int main()
{
 ullong expo=ONE;

 for ( ullong n=0 ; n<N322 ; ++n ) {
     if ( (expo<<=ONE) >= N323 ) expo%=N323;
 } 

 cout<<"REMAINDER = "<<expo<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```

After running the program:

```
REMAINDER = 157
```

[With $\tt WolframAlpha$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%5E322%29mod323):
$$
2^{322}\,{\rm mod}\,323 = \color{#ff0000}{\Large 157}
$$